# i want to send my model class object to next screen previously i do it like this first i declare object in the second screen

Tags: flutter, routes, model, navigation

**Hello i want to send my model class object to next screen previously i do it like this
first i declare object in the second screen where i want to naviagte**

```
 class ContactsDetail extends StatelessWidget {
      ContactModel contactDetail;
      ContactsDetail({Key? key, required this.contactDetail}) : super(key: key);
    
    Then in navigator i passed the argument  
    
        onTap: () async {
                
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return ContactsDetail(
                          contactDetail: contactlist[index],);
                      },
                    ));
                  },`enter code here`
```

**Which works perfectly, Now i am working with name routes and i want to send the whole model of current index data same as i do above but i am unable to do this
Now here is my routes .**

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
switch(settings.name)
{
  case LoginScreen.routeName:
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen());
  case TourDetailScreen.routeName:
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TourDetailScreen());

  default:
    return errorRoute();
}
}

And here is the class to which i want to send data

class TourDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'tourist_detail_screen';
  TourModel tourDetails;
  TourDetailScreen({Key? key,required this.tourDetails}) : super(key: key);

and this is main 
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

        initialRoute: TouristHomeScreen.routeName,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) => generateRoute(settings),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this but here is how I send object of my custom model to next screen

First of all in your genrateRoute declare a variable as your model you want to send

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings){
var tourModel = settings.arguments as TourModel;
```

Inside your case pass the above variable as argument

```
case TourDetailScreen.routeName:
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TourDetailScreen(arguments : tourModel));
```

From where you want to navigate,Navigate like this

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
          return TourDetailScreen(
            arguments: toursList[index],
          );
        })
```

And finally in the screen where you want to navigate

```
TourModel arguments;
TourDetailScreen({Key? key,required this.arguments}) : super(key: key);
```

and use can use arguments where ever you want inside build i.e
`Text(arguments.yourFields)`,

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in named route as well, using  `arguments` parameter of the `Navigator.pushNamed()` method.

```
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
      arguments: ScreenArguments(
        'Extract Arguments Screen',
        'This message is extracted in the build method.',
      ),
    );


// A Widget that extracts the necessary arguments from
// the ModalRoute.
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExtractArgumentsScreen({super.key});

  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute
    // settings and cast them as ScreenArguments.
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ref: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 0):

create class like this:

```
class ContactsDetailArguments {
  final ContactModel contactDetail;

  ContactsDetailArguments({
    @required this.contactDetail,
  });
}
```

and change your ContactsDetail like this:

```
class ContactsDetail extends StatelessWidget {
      ContactsDetailArguments arguments;
      ContactsDetail({Key? key, required this.arguments}) : super(key: key);
...
}
```

then in your route confige do this:

```
var arg = settings.arguments as ContactsDetailArguments;
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(arguments: arg));
```